# How can I embed an SVG in a web page so that the text is highlightable?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG file which I would like to embed in a webpage such that the text is highlightable. However, embedding the SVG seems to prevent the text from being highlighted, and I have not been able to find a way to fix this.

If I open the SVG in my browser, I can highlight the text without any issue, which indicates to me that the SVG file itself is created in such a way that the text is preserved.

However, when I embed the SVG into a webpage, the text is no longer highlightable.

```
<img id="foo" src="bar.svg" width="100%">
```

Opening the SVG in a new tab (right-click, "Open in new tab"), provides an image where the text is highlightable.

Comment: Have you tried embedding the svg directly into the HTML? If you place the SVG's XML content directly into your HTML, it will be treated as a part of the DOM, and its text will be selectable

Comment: Take inspiration from the Native JavaScript [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) I blogged about.

Comment: @Insula - I can't embed it directly since I'm using JS to dynamically load different SVGs. But it looks like embedding the SVG with an <object> tag instead of an <img> tag preserves the text highlightability.

Answer (score 1):

Like commented you can use the object elements for embedding the SVG.

Here is the SVG for the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <rect width="100" height="50" fill="orange" />
  <text x="50" y="25" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="14" fill="SteelBlue">Hello World!</text>
</svg>
```

And here the example using the object element:

```html
<object data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgNTAiPgogIDxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAiIGZpbGw9Im9yYW5nZSIgLz4KICA8dGV4dCB4PSI1MCIgeT0iMjUiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIGRvbWluYW50LWJhc2VsaW5lPSJtaWRkbGUiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTQiIGZpbGw9IlN0ZWVsQmx1ZSI+SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhPC90ZXh0Pgo8L3N2Zz4=" width="300"></object>
```